# object object error in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to execute the following code but getting error:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click", ".generate_report", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var clickedId = this.id.split('-');
        var dbId = clickedId[1];
        var idArray = [];
        $('.clientIps-' + dbId).each(function() {
            idArray.push(this.id);
        });
        idArray.forEach(function(item) {
            // do something with `item`
            var id = $("#" + item);
            alert(id);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `alert()` is not a debugging tool, learn to use `console.log()` or `console.error()` and what do you want to do with item?

Comment: Are you telling us the error or do we have to guess? What do you expect the code to do and what does it do? What have you done to debug the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error. The issue is because you're trying to `alert` a jQuery object. The alert box does not serialise this and instead just shows `[object Object]`. Use `console.log` instead to see more information about the selected element:

```
var id = $("#" + item);
console.log(id);
```